# How to avoid triggering eslint's for..in when using Typescript

Tags: typescript, eslint, typescript-eslint

I currently use the TypeScript recommended approach to iterate over object's keys., like this:

```
    let key: keyof ExampleObject;
    for (key in exampleObject) {
      // do some work with exampleObject[key];
    }
```

In my current project Eslint complains about using `for..in` construct like this:

```
for..in loops iterate over the entire prototype chain, which is virtually never what you want. Use Object.{keys,values,entries}, and iterate over the resulting array      no-restricted-syntax
The body of a for-in should be wrapped in an if statement to filter unwanted properties from the prototype                                                                 guard-for-in
```

I have seen several similar questions and answers for JavaScript e.g. using Object.keys(...) but TypeScript doesn't like this approach too and it loses some of the typesafety.

Is there a way to avoid triggering Eslint rules while still adhering to the TypeScript best practices? I know I can just turn off the designated rules but I hope there is a less 'hacky' way

Comment: I think the es-lint error explains its reasoning quite well, what kind of way are you looking for that'd be less "hacky" then turning the rule off for this block of code?

Comment: @MikeS. I think the problem is that the OP is looking for a type-safe way to do it, and there isn't one (see my answer).

Answer (score 0):

Eslint is complaining for an extremely valid reason, and you should basically never use `for...in` unless you explicitly *want* to walk the prototype chain, which you basically never do.

As for the rest...

> TypeScript doesn't like this approach too and it loses some of the typesafety.

Yeah. Your problem isn't `Object.keys`, your problem is that runtime reflection and compile-time type safety are natural enemies in the wild. So there isn't a 'clean' way to do this, you are saying "give me all of the properties of this object at runtime" which *can't* be safely known at compile-time, and changing the mechanism by which you ask for that isn't going to fix the fundamental underlying issue.

You have a few options for dealing with this.

1. Change your approach. Do you *really* need to iterate over all the keys of that object? *All* of them? Or can you use a compile-time const array of known keys?
2. Use compile-time legible runtime checks like `instanceof`, `typeof`, the `in` operator, etc to narrow the type.
3. Accept the loss of type-safety and use casts to satisfy the compiler.